# How hide links to guest but not for crawler robots?

Tags: php, html, css

How to do that? I have post on my blog. I want hide links to guest but not for any crawler only in php not javascript. I can't find any information on google so please help with any suggestion.

---

```
if ( preg_match("#(google|slurp@inktomi|yahoo! slurp|msnbot)#si", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
// do something after recognize
}
```

Comment: Actually, have you tried any attempts on your own ?

Comment: I thin simple way to resolve this is create database with lists of robots IP. Then PHP see if user is a guest or crawler then display links or info about registration, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use css

```
.link-I-want-to-hide{
    display:none;
}
```

This means the anchor elements will not be physically visible to users, yet exist in the HTML to be parsed by crawlers.

Comment: @Djip, he said he wants the links to be visible to crawlers but not actual users. When you use css above, it will not be visible to actual users, yet still exist in the HTML to be parsed by crawlers

Comment: Yes this what I need. But I need this only on php or include css. This should working on any system with most popular browser. Some browsers don't using javascript or similar.

Comment: @MESSIAH, I imagine that it is much harder on only the php side. This is becuase you will have to do some request sniffing to determine if the request is coming from a normal browser or some sort of bot

Comment: Or we need create database list with crawler IP,

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CSS, just select your HTML elements and apply `display: none`.

Quick example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wz2ryewd/

```
.hide {
    display: none   
}
```

Or alternatively, wrap all your guest links in a div, apply the "hide" class on it:

https://jsfiddle.net/wz2ryewd/1/

Just a SEO note to pay some extra attention ...

> If your site is perceived to contain hidden text and links that are
>   deceptive in intent, your site may be removed from the Google index,
>   and will not appear in search results pages as Google could applies a penalization.

Comment: @MESSIAH You are welcome, if think my answer replied your question, please consider accepting it , click the checkmark under this post, , on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows). Thanks!